# Is there an Event I can trap in KeyCloak when an account is temporarily locked

Tags: keycloak

I'm using KeyCloak 3.4.3.FINAL and looking to see if there is any way I can capture when an account is temporarily locked/unlocked.  I was hoping to write an EventListener that would trigger based on an event type, but I can't seem to find anything that fires when then account is locked.

Is there such an Event in Keycloak?  If not, is there a way I can add my own custom events?  I'd be okay with trapping an AccountModified event and work with that, but the only event I see fired is the LOGIN_ERROR which doesn't tell me if the account is being temporarily disabled/enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around for a while, I figured out there would be a way via the LOGIN_ERROR event finally.  Although at best, it will tell me if the user's account is temporarily locked, but won't tell me when the account is unlocked.

Temporary locks and unlocks are not changes to the account definition itself, but handled by the `BruteForceDetector` class, which manages that information independently.  That is, that only upon explicit requests to the class, can you determine if the account is locked or unlocked.  Upon login, a check is made to the `BruteForceDetector` to determine if the user's account is temporarily locked or not.

```
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    // Ignore excluded events
    if (eevent.getType() == EventType.LOGIN_ERROR) {
        RealmModel realm = session.realms().getRealm(event.getRealmId());
        UserModel user = session.userStorageManager().getUserById(event.getUserId(), realm);
        boolean isTempDisabled = session.getProvider(BruteForceProtector.class).isTemporarilyDisabled(session, realm, user);
        System.out.println("EVENT: " + toString(event) + ", tempDisabled=" + isTempDisabled + ", isEnabled=" + user.isEnabled() );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this session object?

Comment: @kdureidy 

private final KeycloakSession session;
    




public CustomTokenListener(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
  }